# casing the object values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, grid

Hai am using telerik wpf grid

in grid selection change event am getting the selected row values.
the problem is the values are as object.

object myData = radGridView.SelectedItem;

the object myData contains the row values. but i don know how to get values from the myData object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are assigning(or Binding) Collection of MyType to ItemsSource then you will get SelectedItem as object of MyType. All you need to do is

```
MyType myData = radGridView.SelectedItem as MyType;
```

and then you can read the values form myData object.
Hope it helps!!

Comment: hai viky

i did like this, but it returns null. why??
 Array []myData  = radGridView.SelectedItem as Array[];

Comment: as operator returns null upon invalid casting.  Put a breakpoint on the line and examine the type when debugger stops there.

Comment: in tat object one value is string, one is double.

Comment: In your case, you are assigning array of MyType as ItemsSource, so you need to cast the selected item to MyType not to Array of Mytype

Comment: sorry viki .i cant get u.. can u tell me detailed... if u have can look at the simple sample. http://cid-08ec3041618e8ee4.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.SharedFavorites/wpfgridview.rar